# How to set hyperlink for a banner logo. Please help

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to set hyperlink to logo which is at the left side of the banner. when i use

```
<a href="home.php"> <div class="logo"></div></a>
```

its not working. help me to come out of this problem

Comment: What is exactly the problem? could you expand a bit on what you *have* and what you need?

Comment: this should have been at doctype.com. not stackoverflow.

Comment: @Rajasekar: because http://doctype.com is a dedicated site for web design Q&A, while http://stackoverflow.com is for programming Q&A

Comment: voyager"To quote from the SO Blog post: "While we certainly encourage web design questions involving HTML and CSS on Stack Overflow, it’s intended first and foremost for programmers. So if you’re a web designer, and less of a programmer, you might find a better audience for your question (plus some cool auto-screenshot capabilities) at Doctype." – to me that question lives pretty well here. And got answered already anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that since `<a>` is an inline element, while `<div>` is a block element. You should replace your `<div>` with an inline element such as `<span>`, or follow what [Dominic Rodger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389905/how-to-set-hyperlink-for-a-banner-logo-please-help/1389911#1389911) said.

Answer (score 4):

For these sorts of things I do something like this:

```
<div class="logo"><a href="home.php" id="logolink"></a></div>
```

In my CSS:

```
a#logolink { display: block; width: 500px; height: 100px; }
```

Adjusting heights and widths to fit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You can't nest block elements like `<div>` in inline elements like `<a>`. You can put the `<a>` tag around the logo image, though:

```
<a href="home.php">
  <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
</a>
```

Comment: Meh. That was supposed to be a code snippet not a ready-made solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="home.php"><img src='logo.png' /></a>
```